Adding an "Article already read" part underneath a text box that leads to a different Page
so for school we have to programm a website, and mine is about diffent historical topics, the website includes different boxes that include a picture and text, and my goal is to add a small text beneath the Box if you have already the text ( so clicked the box to reach the page with the text )
were allowed to use HTML, CSS and Javascript.
Heres the Box code, followed by the CSS (ignore the Text Parts in German)


.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.container .inner-container {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 50px;
}

h1 {

  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #52565a;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px aliceblue solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}

.box:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <a href="/Weiterleitung/rom.html" class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="Römische Stadt">
            <div class="box-text">
                <h2>Rom (800BC-500 AD)</h2>
                <p>Die Antike war eine Epoche im Mittelmeerraum von 800 vor Christus bis 500 nach Christus. Normalerweise bezeichnest du damit das antike Griechenland und das Römische Reich.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>



I tied AI, different Websites but found nothing, thanks in advance

You can store this in the browsers localStorage using javascript. Then check localStorage each time the page is loaded and if the user has this in their localStorage, redirect the user to the other page or show hidden content, etc...

Thanks for the answer, do you have anywhere i can concretly read into this? its my first longer project with html so any input is helpful

Maybe the documentation for localStorage would be a good place to start?

If I properly understand you can use javascript with eventlistener such as mouseover, when the user mouseover a text appears below the card giving him the possibility to read another card

As mentioned in my comment above if you need to add a text once the user reads the card (supposedely by hovering over it), you can use event listener mouseover as below. you can also use an array to store the different urls (card2, card3..) and change it for each visited page.


const box = document.querySelector('.box')
const textAddedOnHoverSpan = document.querySelector('.added-text-onhover')
let card2="https://www.example.com"
let visited  = localStorage.getItem('visited') ?? "false" // set default value to string "false"
console.log(visited)

if(visited==="true") {
    console.log(visited)
    box.style.backgroundColor= "yellow" //if already visited colored in red
    textAddedOnHoverSpan.innerHTML = `You already read this card, you can visit <a href="${card2}" >next one</a>`
}else{
    box.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{
        localStorage.setItem("visited", "true")
        console.log(visited)
        textAddedOnHoverSpan.innerHTML = `You already read this card, you can visit <a href="${card2}" >next one</a>`
        box.style.backgroundColor= "blue" // if first time visited colored in blue
    })
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column; /*added this line to have added text beneath the card*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.container .inner-container {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 50px;
}

h1 {

  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #52565a;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px aliceblue solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}

.box:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <a href="/Weiterleitung/rom.html" class="box">
          <div class="box-content">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="Römische Stadt">
              <div class="box-text">
                  <h2>Rom (800BC-500 AD)</h2>
                  <p>Die Antike war eine Epoche im Mittelmeerraum von 800 vor Christus bis 500 nach Christus. Normalerweise bezeichnest du damit das antike Griechenland und das Römische Reich.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <span class="added-text-onhover"></span>  
  </div>




Great answer however this will not persist if the user refreshes the page.

Thks a lot! trust me not a big thing by learning you will do better than that. You are right if you want this to stay even on page refresh you will need to use localstorage  to store a value that you will check its presence (here I used "visited" and value is string either "true" or "false". You can use boolean (then you need to use JSON.parse, just kept it simple). So I  am updating my code, that you need to see in you code editor as localStorage don't work in SO.

Also if you want to have more than one card per page you will need to use event.target to check which card is mouseovered.

@dalelandry pls note that this will not working on small screen as you have a a tag inside .box
